# FindAll search question

Tags: c#, list, findall

I have a list like this:

```
item.Add("a");
item.Add("as");
item.Add("b");
item.Add("fgs");
item.Add("adsd");
```

How can I find all items that start with (for example) "a"?

This "a" is not some hardcoded string, so I will need a function that do this for each string.

I try with FindAll, but I did not figured out how it works.

Br, Wolfy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "start with" you mean the first char, then:

```
item.FindAll(i => i[0] == 'a');
```

if you mean a string (may be other than 1 char) then:

```
item.FindAll(i => i.StartsWith("a"));
```

If you want a different comparison, such as case-insensitive, locale-based, etc. then do the relevant IndexOf such as:

```
item.FindAll(i => i.IndexOf("a", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

All of the above can be easily adapted to be use a relevant char or string variable or parameter.

If you don't need the extra properties and methods provided by a list, then it will be more efficient to use `Where` than `FindAll` as `FindAll` creates a new list, and does so in all at once, while `Where` will enumerate the matching results as it is iterated through.

Answer (score 2):

Or with LINQ

```
from i in items where i.StartsWith("a") select i;
```

Answer (score 1):

for NET2.0    you may use this method:
'pattern' is an argument to look for (f.e. "a")

```
    private List<string> FindAll(List<string> list, string pattern)
    {       // returns found results
            return list.FindAll(delegate(string item)
                            {
                                return item.StartsWith(pattern);

                            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you have another list that contains the startswith criteria strings. Lets call your items "words" and the other list "keywords". So the below query will return what you want.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.Add("a");
words.Add("as");
words.Add("b");
words.Add("fgs");
words.Add("adsd");

List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("a");
keywords.Add("b");

var result = words.FindAll(o =>
    keywords.Any(a => o.StartsWith(a))
);
```

This result has the words that starts with any of the keyword from keywords.

Comment: +1 I think this is what OP want. And a suggestion: change the variable name from "list" to "keywords" and change "item" to "words".

Comment: Thanks Danny Chen. I have edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> item = new List<string>();
            item.Add("a");
            item.Add("as");
            item.Add("b");
            item.Add("fgs");
            item.Add("adsd");

            var res1 = item.FindAll(i => i.StartsWith("a"));
            var res2 = item.Where(i => i.StartsWith("a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
item.FindAll(i => i.Contains("a"));
```

This will return a List containting only the filtered strings.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`?

Comment: @Brian: Should have been StartsWith. I read his question a bit to quick.